# Displaying records section wise in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch

I have three mutable arrays all need to be loaded into a table as different sections. But, I found that `NSTableView` does not support sections, how do I display the list section wise?

Answer (score 5):

Just google a bit and you will get [this sample](http://www.noodlesoft.com/blog/2009/09/25/sticky-section-headers-in-nstableview/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the class `NSOutlineView`, which supports this sort of thing. It is a subclass of `NSTableView`.

The data model and delegate protocols are slightly more complex, but not much. There is more information in Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). There are also quite a few tutorials made by other developers out there, which google will uncover for you.